# iterate images from array to class img src in class javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 classes named box and box2, box2 can be dragged to box1 then p element and backgroundcolor get deleted.

I have an arrayVariable[] of 10 values and ArrayOfImages[] of 10 images with same name as arrayVariable values.

I randomly selected a value for p from arrayvariable , the corresponding image values are taken and stored in an array named tempimages.

I have tried to display the images stored in tempimages to image src of class box2 so that each image can be used for drop.

tempimage[0] is displayed on page , but next image will not be seen after droping.

How do i achieve it?

```js
function rvalue() {
  var array = [];
  var tempimages = [];
  var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
  var ArrayOfImages = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg'];

  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
  for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
    ptags[i].textContent = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];

    array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
    tempimages.push(`${ptags[i].textContent}.jpg`);
    document.querySelector("#slide").style.background = "url(" + tempimages[i] + ")" // i want to display images in tempimages to img src of box2 on each drop how to do it?  
  }
  console.log(array);
  console.log(tempimages);
}



function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}


function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var el = document.getElementById(data);

  el.parentNode.removeChild; // deleting drag item

  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = 'initial'; //[value indicate which box elemenet] bgcoclor none
  var pParagraph = ev.target.firstElementChild;
  console.log(pParagraph);
  ev.target.removeChild(pParagraph);


  alert(el);
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: #c65353;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.box2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  background-color: #ffff00 2px;
}

p {
  font: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
    <p name="values">dsbd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
    <p name="values">tyjt</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
    <p name="values">tjyt</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
    <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" style="width:50px; height:50px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: drap the box2 to box1 top portion so that p element  and background get deleted